# How to receive specific interface's array in PHP class method?

Tags: php, arrays, namespaces

I want to receive array of MyInterface as the in the below code.

```
public function saveMultiple(
    \Path\To\MyInterface $attachLinks[]
);
```

The above code doesn't work.

So please don't tell me that just remove `\Path\To\MyInterface` and to use a variable `$attachLinks`. I'm already aware of that but this is something which I require.

Comment: which php version did you use?

Comment: Good, I was looking for that and you saved my time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is what can be done using `PHP7`. Till date passing arrays with specific type is not possible.

```
public function saveMultiple(
    array $attachLinks
);
```

It'll now at least make sure that the method only gets array as parameter.

Comment: The person who down voted here must comment as well with explaining reason. How you can be better judge of something that I've asked???

Answer (score 1):

There are no generic types in php, so you can not specify type «array of something».

But you may do a trick. Check types of elements in array.

```
array_walk($attachLinks, function (\Path\To\MyInterface $item) {});
```

If you wrap it in assert, you will be able to disable this check.

```
assert('array_walk($attachLinks, function (\Path\To\MyInterface $item) {})');
```

Comment: That won't achieve the purpose of enforcing passing array type of interfaces.

Comment: Yes. It is not exactly what you want. It's workaround that allows you to be sure that the code won't be executed with incorrect items in array.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use some type of setter like:

```
private $attachLinks = [];
public function setter(MyInterface $var)
{
    $this->attachLinks[] = $var;
}
```

And than use a $this->attachLinks in your function

```
public function saveMultiple() {
    print_r($this->attachLinks);
}
```